# Bluetooth permission issue

Tags: android, arduino

I am trying to stablish serial communication between android studio and arduino, but i have this Fatal Exception.

> Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission for
> android.content.AttributionSource@71c08a09: AdapterService
> getBondedDevices

I have added the permission in the manifest, this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.ovo" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_hojita"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_hojita"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.OVO"
        tools:targetApi="33" >
        <activity
            android:name=".WifiCredentialActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"> ...
```

This is the code in the activity:

```
    package com.example.ovo
        
        import android.Manifest
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
        import android.content.pm.PackageManager
        import android.os.Bundle
        import android.util.Log
        import android.view.WindowManager
        import android.widget.Button
        import android.widget.Toast
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
        import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
        import com.harrysoft.androidbluetoothserial.BluetoothManager
        import com.harrysoft.androidbluetoothserial.BluetoothSerialDevice
        import com.harrysoft.androidbluetoothserial.SimpleBluetoothDeviceInterface
        import com.harrysoft.androidbluetoothserial.SimpleBluetoothDeviceInterface.OnMessageReceivedListener
        import com.harrysoft.androidbluetoothserial.SimpleBluetoothDeviceInterface.OnMessageSentListener
        import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
        import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
    
    
    class WifiCredentialActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        val bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager = BluetoothManager.getInstance()
        private var deviceInterface: SimpleBluetoothDeviceInterface? = null
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi_credential)
            getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            )
    
            if (bluetoothManager == null) {
                // Bluetooth unavailable on this device :( tell the user
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not available.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show() // Replace context with your context instance.
                finish()
            }
            val pairedDevices: Collection<BluetoothDevice> = bluetoothManager.pairedDevicesList
            for (device in pairedDevices) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return
                }
                Log.d("My Bluetooth App", "Device name: " + device.name)
                Log.d("My Bluetooth App", "Device MAC Address: " + device.address)
                // Here ill try to connect with the device
            }
    
        }
    
        private fun connectDevice(mac: String) {
            bluetoothManager.openSerialDevice(mac)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ connectedDevice: BluetoothSerialDevice -> onConnected(connectedDevice) }) { error: Throwable ->
                    onError(
                        error
                    )
                }
        }
    
        private fun onConnected(connectedDevice: BluetoothSerialDevice) {
            // You are now connected to this device!
            // Here you may want to retain an instance to your device:
            deviceInterface = connectedDevice.toSimpleDeviceInterface()
    
            // Listen to bluetooth events
            deviceInterface?.setListeners(
                OnMessageReceivedListener { message: String -> onMessageReceived(message) },
                OnMessageSentListener { message: String -> onMessageSent(message) },
                SimpleBluetoothDeviceInterface.OnErrorListener { error: Throwable ->
                    onError(
                        error
                    )
                })
    
            // Let's send a message:
            deviceInterface?.sendMessage("Hello world!")
        }
    
        private fun onMessageSent(message: String) {
            // We sent a message! Handle it here.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sent a message! Message was: $message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show() // Replace context with your context instance.
        }
    
        private fun onMessageReceived(message: String) {
            // We received a message! Handle it here.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Received a message! Message was: $message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show() // Replace context with your context instance.
        }
    
        private fun onError(error: Throwable) {
            // Handle the error
        }
    }
```

Im using this library https://github.com/harry1453/android-bluetooth-serial , my guess is that i have to call the function that says in the TODO part, but i dont know how.

thank you in advance, i appreciate the help.